# C# write class object to binary file in one step

Tags: c#, c++, binaryfiles, binary-data

Ok, In C++ I could create a struct object that contains a bunch of value types and when needed write it out to a binary file in a single write statement like this:

```
struct DataFileHeader {
  unsigned short Id;
  unsigned short Type;
  unsigned int Count;
  unsigned int Offset;
};

...

struct DataFileHeader dataFileHeader;

...
rc = _write(fileHandle, &dataFileHeader, 12);
```

Is there any way to do that in c#?  I've converted my structs to classes in c# and am working with the BinaryFormatter and trying to serialize the object but that adds a bunch of text and other stuff to the stream.  I just want to write out the all the value fields in the object.   Is this possible or do I have to write out each field on the object separatly?

Comment: it's not difficult to write your own binary BinaryFormatter.

Comment: Why not using the existing BinaryFormatter

Comment: @ilansch, because it stuffs a ton of "text" in the stream.  Things like DLL Name, Version, Culture, Field Names.  Instead of just 12 bytes it returns 169.

Answer (score 0):

```
void Main()
{
    var fileHeader = new DataFileHeader()
    {
        Count = 10,
        Id = 10,
        Offset = 10,
        Type = 10
    };

    Serialize(fileHeader).Dump();
}

// Define other methods and classes here
public byte[] Serialize<TObject>(TObject obj)
{
    BinaryFormatter binaryFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    byte[] ret = null;
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        binaryFormatter.Serialize(ms, obj);
        ret = ms.ToArray();
    }
    return ret;
}

[Serializable]
public struct DataFileHeader
{
    public short Id;
    public short Type;
    public int Count;
    public int Offset;
};
```

If that doesn't work I think doing it individually might be the only way.

```
BitConverter.GetBytes(fileHeader.Count).Concat(BitConverter.GetBytes(fileHeader.Count)).Concat(BitConverter.GetBytes(fileHeader.Count)).Concat(BitConverter.GetBytes(fileHeader.Count)).Dump();
```

Comment: This doesn't work because as stated previously the BinaryFormatter stuffs a bunch of junk in the stream about DLL name, version, culture... etc.  I just want the Binary data of the fields, nothing else.  If the ms.ToArray() returned 12 bytes that would be great but it doesn't it returns 169.

Comment: Then probably doing it individually on the property is ur best bet

Comment: Also the reason it does that is because it has to know the type when deserializing

Comment: I understand why "serializing" adds all the information but that doesn't work when you need the data in an exact format.  Out of curiosity why do you keep adding .Dump()?  That's not a method I'm seeing anywhere?

Comment: I use Linqpad for my testing code which has a nice Dump() method to print the contents of an object in a nice way.